# formating currency to K for Kilo or M for Million

Tags: visualforce

Is there a function or way to format currency or money If I want them to be shorter. Example if the value becomes 10,000 I want it to become 10K or If it is 1,000,000 to 1M?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it for displaying purposes only? In that case you could use a formula field. You will loose the currency formatting, though (e.g. dollar sign)

Something like:

```
IF(Money__c > 1000000,
   ROUND(Money__c/1000000,0) + 'M'
   ,
   if(
      Money__c > 1000
      ,
      ROUND(Money__c/1000,0) + 'K'
      ,
      Money__c
   )
)
```

In case you need to have an editable field, that might work on a VisualForce page with some background processing.. Certainly no standard functionality and will not work on standard page layouts.

Comment: This doesn't matter anymore, I handle this using a JavaScript. :)